# How to validate Grafana's json file against 3.1 version

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I'd like to share my dashboard to Grafana community, but at the upload page the json isn't validated as "Old dashboard JSON format". it isn't clear which part is wrong or missing. How I can upgrade it and what particular part can be missed there?

[image]

I have added `__inputs` part according to https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.5/dashboards/export-import/ , but it is still impossible to upload the file.

P.S. Upload page is specific to my account and is: https://grafana.com/orgs/eljah/dashboards?pg=dashboards&plcmt=usr-upload

Grafana version according to helm chart is:

```
- name: grafana
  repository: https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
  version: 6.1.17
```

UPD2.

Can't figure out SHare option on the Grafana ui: [image]

Comment: Which Grafana version did you use for dashboard exporting and how did you export dashboard?

Comment: `- name: grafana`
`  repository: https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts`
`  version: 6.1.17`

Comment: I have a grafana installe with helm chart ccording to the config I have just posted

Comment: I try to upload them at this page: https://grafana.com/orgs/eljah/dashboards?pg=dashboards&plcmt=usr-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how did you export dashboard. Please follow doc https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/export-import/#exporting-a-dashboard and check "Export for sharing externally". Then you can publish your dashboard on grafana.com portal without any modification of exported json file.

Comment: I can't find the share button according to the description on the page. Please see my screenshot:

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev you have provided your Grafana version (finally) - it is 7.3.5, so https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.3/dashboards/export-import/#exporting-a-dashboard

Comment: I have succeed with than. Now i'm searching the text markup rules for Readme part of dashboard description since want to post some configuration in code style her, but is is a WiSYWIG with unknown rules.  https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/16353 - I'd like to convert the description to code style while it looks like a bunch of paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

@JanGaraj has explained the right answer.

But I had some problems with finding a control to do a dashboard share. Finally it was fount there:

[image]